# Polymer RESTful CRUD app

Tags: polymer

I have a Users resource that consumes and produces JSON.
I want to make RESTful calls (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) in Polymer.

Any example app or link to resources.

Comment: currently there is nothing like a component build for making rest apis, in current scenario core-ajax is the way to go by setting method attribute to fetch the response

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made this Polymer app for an Open Source domotic project:

https://github.com/NikZar/nautes-freedomotic-dashboard

You can take a look at my: [**fd-rest-element-service.html**](https://github.com/NikZar/nautes-freedomotic-dashboard/blob/master/app/elements/fd-rest-element-service.html) and see how it gets used in the application.

I hope this helps :)