# How to make a Polymer CRUD app?

Tags: polymer

Does anyone know any example/tutorial of Polymer using core-ajax and ajax-form to build a CRUD application?

My main question is how to structure the app (best practices) to focus data access in "modules" (custom elements) like in Angular services.

Should I use a unique core-ajax by "module" for example and change this attributes (like url and method) in javascript or put multiple core-ajax in template? I know this is maybe a personal choice, but if an idea for this already exists I would follow it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best choice is use Firebase!

http://polymer.github.io/firebase-element

Also there is the AngularJS binding for Firebase

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html

Comment: Thanks, but my customer requires MSSQL Server, so I thought I'd use WEB API for REST

Comment: Hope this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600326/polymer-restful-crud-app and http://www.zenqry.com/

Comment: @Oswaldo: I agree. Firebase is the best option. Train your customer to use Firebase!